# Best way for communication between applications to one application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm using C++ MFC.

I wonder what is the best way to communicate between X applications to one application that behave like "Application Manager"

I'm considering  to use SendMessge (Win32 Api) and dont know if there is a better way to do that ( like sockets )

I would like to get some suggestions about this issue. Advantages and disadvantages are welcomed!

Thanks

Comment: Are your applications communicating over a network, no need to consider sockets unless that is true.

Comment: Seems like a server/client structure, there are too many ways out there. Take a look into sockets or GSOAP (they're using sockets too).

Comment: If `SendMessage` does what you need, just use that.  Anything else will increase your program's complexity a lot.

Comment: Use SendMessageTimeout

Comment: You can always use pipes and file mappings, but SendMessage seems the easier way. I advise against using sockets, unless you want communication between processes across a network.

Comment: Search for a shared memory solution.

Comment: Thanks!, SendMessage if faster then Sockets? If i.e the messages sent to the manager each 10ms (from each application) SendMessage performace will decrease, my app will hang?

Comment: Any **synchronous** operation of the server will share the client's fate. If the client hangs, then so does your server. While servicing a client synchronously, the server cannot service any other clients. If you need to serve multiple clients simultaneously, you need asynchronous communication. (Named) pipes are a solution. If performance is an issue, look into I/O Completion Ports as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You app is C/S structure. X app is client, and app manager is Server.
You can use DataBase, SendMessage and Socket to communication between S and C.

**1. SendMessage/Mailslots/Pipes/File Mapping/Shared Memory**

- Advantages: easy to implement
- Disadvantages: C and S should be in the same environment(PC). C and S
  should be implemented at Windows. And there is no communication
  history recording.

**2. DataBase**

- Advantages: C and S can be deployed at different environment and can
  be implemented by different programming languages. And you
  communication history can be tracked.
- Disadvantages: need more effort to implement.

**3. Socket**

- Advantages: C and S can be deployed at different environment and can
  be implemented by different programming languages.
- Disadvantages: need more effort to implement.

Usually, DB & Socket is for complex communication/logic software design which need history recording. And you can choose SendMessage if your communication is not much complex.

Comment: Thanks!, SendMessage if faster then Sockets? If i.e the messages sent to the manager each 10ms (from each application) SendMessage performace will decrease, my app will hang?

Comment: You should add [Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780.aspx), and possibly [Mailslots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576.aspx) to the list.

Comment: Ideally, SendMessage will be faster than Socket. Since the data sent by SendMessage don't touch with the network time-cost operation, such as network protocol. And if the manager don't process the message quickly, the app will hang. You can use PostMessage to ignore waiting manager's message process.

Comment: What @IInspectable said plus Memory Mapped Files.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable for the suggestion. I've added some other IPC methods.